# How do I rewrite a specific path for a single host in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to rewrite `https://test.example.com/assets/*` to `https://test.example.com/public/assets/*`, but otherwise not touch other paths.  How do I achieve this?  My current version doesn't cut it:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /public/$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /.*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: example
            port:
              name: http
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: example
            port:
              name: http
  - host: test.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: (/assets/.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-test
            port:
              name: http

      - path: /.*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-test
            port:
              name: http
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-test
            port:
              name: http
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [server-snippet](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/)? using server snippets you can redirect the traffic to your preferred location instead of actually rewriting it, Have you checked this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69182868)

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde Thanks, that's useful! All the examples I've seen are without a hostname though, which I guess I need. Any ideas if this is supported?

Comment: can you check this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/u1h92o/how_to_add_ingressnginx_serversnipped_only_for/?rdt=61923) and let me know if it is useful.